# Equivalent of Python's "all" function in Mathematica

Tags: programming, prime-numbers

The Python function

```py
 def isPrime(n):
    return all(n % i for i in xrange(2, n))
```

checks if a number is a prime number by using `all`.

How can I write a function similar to `all` in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Have a look at `PrimeQ`.

Comment: I mean which function in mma eqv. python' all

Comment: While such questions doubtless have a theoretical value, one can wonder how fruitful it is, in general, to try to reproduce in one programming language the functions and paradigms of another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*initial side note*: As J.M. correctly points out this is not an efficient implementation and serves only to illustrate behavior similar to the Python function `all`.

If you are looking for a similar definition to the Python code you give, then you could use this:

```
 isPrime[n_] := And @@ Table[Mod[n, i] != 0, {i, Range[2, n - 1]}]
```

This creates a table of either `True` or `False` for each `i` in the range, and the `And@@` means it replaces the head of the list, turning `{True,False,True,...}` (Which is equivalent to `List[True,False,True,...]`) into `And[True,False,True,...]` and thus evaluates to true only if they are all true.

You can then find primes under 20 using:

```
Select[Range@20, isPrime]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
> ```

This however includes 1, which it should not. You could also just use the build in prime checker:

```
Select[Range@20, PrimeQ]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
> ```

**Update**

To elaborate, `all` in python takes an iterable object and returns true if all iterations are true. For the Mathematica code, `And@@` is used on a realised list of booleans and returns `True` if they are all true. So they are not strictly the same, but typically in Mathematica you do not have language specified "iterables".

You could pass around unevaluated iteration specfications quite simply however, allowing you to iterate in any way you see fit in functions that take these specifications as input. For instance implementing an `all`-like function that can short circuit on the very first False found:

```
 SetAttributes[iterable, HoldAll]

 myAll[iterable[exp_, {var_, lower_, upper_}]] := 
 Module[{run = upper >= lower, i = lower},
 While[run,
  If[exp /. var -> i,
   If[i == upper, Return[True], i++], Return[False]];
 ]; True
 ]
```

Allowing the prime function you gave to be defined as:

```
 dprimeQ[n_] := myAll[iterable[Mod[n, i] != 0, {i, 2, n - 1}]]

 Select[Range@20, dprimeQ]
```

> ```
> {1,2,3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
> ```

Which still includes 1 however.

Comment: This is exactly what I want，Thanks.

Comment: `isPrime[]` is not very efficient compared to the built-in `PrimeQ[]`, of course. Here's an alternative definition: `isPrime[n_Integer?Positive] := And @@ Thread[Mod[n, Range[2, n - 1]] != 0]`

Comment: @J.M. True, but the question wasn't about an efficient implementation but one that is similar to the Python one. I felt that this was the closest you could get without actually going into handling the iteration unevaluated, and staying close to "typical" Mathematica code.

Comment: Additionally, here's a "short-circuiting" version: `isPrime[n_Integer?Positive] := Catch[Fold[If[! #2, Throw[#2], #1 && #2] &, True, Thread[Mod[n, Range[2, n - 1]] != 0]]]`

Comment: @J.M. Your last solution doesn't seem to actually short circuit. You are still computing all the comparisons at once (`Thread[Mod[n, Range[2, n - 1]] != 0]`) but then short circuiting the following traversal (which I suspect And already does internally). Consider a slower comparison, for instance `(Pause[1];Mod[n,i]!=0)` and test with isPrime[8]. For your version it takes 6 seconds on my system, while the solution posted in my answer returns after just 1 second.

Comment: Hmm, right. I suppose `NestWhile[]` might have to be used for a genuine short-circuit...

Comment: The reason `Select[Range@20, isPrime]` includes 1 in the result is interesting.  (Specifically, it's *not* because `Mod[1,n]==1` for n>0.).

Comment: @BrettChampion Correct, it's because `Range[2,1-1]=>{}`, and `And@@{}=>True`. I suppose this is a difference in the way `And` and Pythons all operate on a range. You can code your way around this, but for the purpose of just showing a method similar to Pythons iterables, I felt simplicity trumped correctness in this edge case.